# Atomic wait memory_order

Tags: c++, c++20, atomic, memory-barriers, stdatomic

I don't completely understand why atomic wait needs a memory order parameter. It compares its own value, so the atomic value itself is synchronized anyway. I couldn't figure out an example where anything else than `std::memory_order_relaxed` makes sense.

If I need additional logic based on the atomic variable I need to call other functions (with separate memory order specification) anyway, as wait is void, e.g.:

```
void waitToBeEmpty() noexcept
{
    ssize_t currSize{ m_queueSize.load(std::memory_order_acquire) };
    while (currSize > 0) {
        m_queueSize.wait(currSize, std::memory_order_relaxed);
        currSize = m_queueSize.load(std::memory_order_acquire);
    }
}
```

Why do we need to specify a memory order for atomic wait?

Comment: Access to your `std::atomic` is always synchronized.  The `memory_order` parameter describes how to synchronize with _all other_ memory accesses in the current thread.  It restricts instruction reordering.

Comment: @DrewDormann: Also restricts run-time reordering, which can be a thing for loads on non-x86 ISAs.  I expect `wait` is equivalent to an `acquire` or `seq_cst` load that sees a value `!= currSize`.  Note that if `m_queueSize` is already `!= currSize`, it doesn't sleep *at all*, just a load / compare and branch.

Comment: @DrewDormann Thanks, it takes a while to adapt this mindset :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If I need additional logic based on the atomic variable I need to call other functions

Do you?

Consider if `T` is a `bool`. It only has one of two states: `true` or `false`. If you `wait` until it is not `true`, then it must be `false` and no further atomic operations are needed.

And that's just the case where `T` is a type that can only (generally) assume two values. There are also cases where `T` is a type that technically can assume more values, but you're only using two of them. Or the cases where `T` could have multiple values, but your waiting code doesn't care which one it is, merely that it isn't the one you asked to wait on. "Is not zero" is a common example, as you may not care which kind of "not zero" it is.